# Eclipse Debugger Events

Tags: eclipse, debugging, events, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse plugin, I would like to be notified on debugger events (e.g. when stepping or a breakpoint is hit). I've managed to get this working in a JDT environment by subscribing to debug events using this code:

```
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(this);
```

Which gives this event handler:

```
public void handleDebugEvents(DebugEvent[] events)
{
}
```

In JDT this is fired on Breakpoint or Suspend events and I was hoping the behaviour would be the same in CDT. However, it is not. I only get two Create events at the start of the debug session:

> DebugEvent[org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.launching.GDBProcess@ae0aae, CREATE, UNSPECIFIED]
>   DebugEvent[org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess@920d5d, CREATE, UNSPECIFIED]

Is there a generic solution that wouldn't require specific dependencies on JDT or CDT?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution and have answered my other question here: [Eclipse plugin - handling events when stepping or breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294820/eclipse-plugin-handling-events-when-stepping-or-breaking/6304013#6304013)

Alan

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can't be achieved (generic, implementation-independent solution) without listening and digging through every single action in the Eclipse environment, as I understand that the Eclipse generic debug plug-in is just the framework on which to build a implementation-specific debugger, like Java's own debugger.

The static call you're making to `DebugPlugin` is a call to this basic 'framework' on which the CDT or JDT is running. For example, if I wanted to register a breakpoint listener to the Java debugger, I would call `JDIDebugModel.addJavaBreakpointListener(<Your Java breakpoint listener class>);`.

P.S. If there is a way to maybe listen to just the events fired from/under the generic platform debug plug-in, which would include the events fired from plug-ins that extend from this generic debugger, that may ease the task you seek to accomplish.