# Activate Eclipse Plugin When User Starts Debugging Session

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have read about the [lazy evaluation plugin loading idea of Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_does_a_plug-in_get_started%3F). I also read about how one can circumvent it and [activate the plugin on Eclipse startup](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Can_I_activate_my_plug-in_when_the_workbench_starts%3F) (via [org.eclipse.ui.startup](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html)). However, I do not want to do that, because it is considered bad practice and it would be too early for my plugin to load. But I depend on the fact that my plugin is activated once the user starts a debugging session. So how can I do that? I tried to add an `IExecutionListener` to the `ICommandService` in order to detect the debug start action, but unfortunately this is also only called after my plugin is activated. So how can I activate my plugin once the user starts a debugging session?

<sup><sub>If someone is curious about why I need to do that: The executing code will call methods over Java RMI. Therefore, Java RMI needs to be started by my plugin before the code is executed.</sub></sup>

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294820/eclipse-plugin-handling-events-when-stepping-or-breaking Its regarding events when stepping/breaking during debug

Comment: Thanks, I already had a look at it. Unfortunately, this also does not work (debug start events are not created or plugin is not activated early enough, not sure atm).

Comment: Is there a solution after all these years?